# How Do I Set A variable Inside a Update Procedure before the Update Command in SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server, variables, set, procedure

I am creating a procedure that will calculate declining depreciation for a fixed asset.
For this I need to set a value inside the procedure based on a CASE which in turn is based on the values from the tables I use in the Update command.
I need to know how to set that variable before I update the Table.
The problem looks something like this:

```
Create procedure Depreciation
as begin
declare @k numeric (10,2) 
set @k=case 
when Value From a table inside the FROM(UPDATE)>1 then 2
else 3
end
update Deprectiation Table set (Deprectiation=@k*Value)
From Tables
where conditions
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's a wrong syntax.You can do something like below (Though your posted code is not at all clear and not sure what you are trying to achieve)

```
Create procedure Depreciation
as 
begin
declare @k numeric (10,2); 
declare @value numeric (10,2); 
select @value = [Value], @k = case when [Value] > 1 then 2 else 3 end 
From table1 ;

update Deprectiation set Deprectiation=@k*@value where conditions;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Create Procedure Description
AS Begin
    Update DeprectiationTable 
    SET Deprectiation=CASE WHEN Value>1 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END * Value
    From Tables
    Where conditions 
End
```